# Is this implementation of PDO and MySQL secure against MySQL Injections?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been studying PDO style of PHP's extensions to do MySQL queries in a secure way. I'm wondering if I've done this correctly to where I can trust it is secure against MySQL injections and such? Any confirmation or corrections would be much appreciated!

```
<?php
$nametosearch=$_POST['nametosearch'];// Is "Billy"

$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.'; dbname='.DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD);//the all caps are PHP constants.

$query =  "SELECT * FROM ".DBNAME.".sometable WHERE username=".$db->quote($nametosearch)." ORDER BY lastname ASC;";

$result = $db->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    //Do some stuff with results
                }

$result->closeCursor();
$db = null;
?>
```

Comment: Use prepared statements instead of quoting data.

Comment: Is the table name DBNAME ? .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not good the way you build your queries, you should use prepared statement to be on the safe side:

```
<?php
$nametosearch=$_POST['nametosearch'];// Is "Billy"

$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.'; dbname='.DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD);//the all caps are PHP constants.

$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".DBNAME.".sometable WHERE username=":username" ORDER BY lastname ASC;");

$statement->execute(array(':username', $nametosearch));

//....
?>
```

this is the secure way to do DB queries using PDO.